# I have a problem building a project on IDEA: Execution failed for task ':desktop:commonizeCInterop'

Tags: intellij-idea

> Task :desktop:commonizeCInterop FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':desktop:commonizeCInterop'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':desktop:kotlinKlibCommonizerClasspath'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':desktop:compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
> > No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=11, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}.
> > No locally installed toolchains match (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:auto_detection) and toolchain download repositories have not been configured (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/toolchains.html#sub:download_repositories).

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':desktop:commonizeCInterop'.
  .
  .
  .
  org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:42)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:31)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty$PropertyQueryException: Failed to calculate the value of task ':desktop:compileJava' property 'javaCompiler'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:248)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.beforeRead(AbstractProperty.java:239)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.calculateOwnValue(AbstractProperty.java:135)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateOwnPresentValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:93)
  at org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin.computeCompatibilityConvention(JavaBasePlugin.java:318)
  at org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin.computeSourceCompatibilityConvention(JavaBasePlugin.java:298)
  at org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin.lambda$configureCompileDefaults$7(JavaBasePlugin.java:290)
  at org.gradle.util.internal.GUtil.uncheckedCall(GUtil.java:437)
  at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ConventionAwareHelper$2.doGetValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:96)
  at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ConventionAwareHelper$MappedPropertyImpl.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:147)
  at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ConventionAwareHelper.getConventionValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:129)
  at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile_Decorated.getSourceCompatibility(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin.computeTargetCompatibilityConvention(JavaBasePlugin.java:304)
  at org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin.lambda$configureCompileDefaults$8(JavaBasePlugin.java:291)
  at org.gradle.util.internal.GUtil.uncheckedCall(GUtil.java:437)
  at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ConventionAwareHelper$2.doGetValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:96)
  at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ConventionAwareHelper$MappedPropertyImpl.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:147)
  at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.ConventionAwareHelper.getConventionValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:129)
  at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile_Decorated.getTargetCompatibility(Unknown Source)
  at org.gradle.api.plugins.jvm.internal.DefaultJvmPluginServices.lambda$configureDefaultTargetPlatform$6(DefaultJvmPluginServices.java:219)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.preventFromFurtherMutation(DefaultConfiguration.java:1125)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.preventFromFurtherMutation(DefaultConfiguration.java:1113)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultLocalComponentMetadataBuilder.createConfiguration(DefaultLocalComponentMetadataBuilder.java:70)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultLocalComponentMetadataBuilder.addConfiguration(DefaultLocalComponentMetadataBuilder.java:44)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.addConfiguration(DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.java:120)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.getRootComponentMetadata(DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.java:114)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.lambda$buildRootComponentMetadata$0(DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.java:104)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:406)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.buildRootComponentMetadata(DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.java:102)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.toRootComponentMetaData(DefaultRootComponentMetadataBuilder.java:88)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.toRootComponentMetaData(DefaultConfiguration.java:1344)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$DefaultResolveContextToComponentResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:230)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:140)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:144)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:195)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:85)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:76)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$1.call(DefaultConfiguration.java:669)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$1.call(DefaultConfiguration.java:660)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:660)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.lambda$resolveExclusively$4(DefaultConfiguration.java:640)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$CalculatedModelValueImpl.update(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:486)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveExclusively(DefaultConfiguration.java:637)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:624)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1900(DefaultConfiguration.java:166)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$SelectedArtifactsProvider.getValue(DefaultConfiguration.java:1505)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$SelectedArtifactsProvider.getValue(DefaultConfiguration.java:1495)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getSelectedArtifacts(DefaultConfiguration.java:1574)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:1561)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.visitContents(DefaultConfiguration.java:521)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:366)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.lambda$calculateFinalizedValue$0(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:241)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:67)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection$UnresolvedItemsCollector.visitContents(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:370)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.calculateFinalizedValue(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:241)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultConfigurableFileCollection.java:272)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:124)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:366)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:124)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:67)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.UnpackingVisitor.add(UnpackingVisitor.java:92)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileCollectionFactory$ResolvingFileCollection.visitChildren(DefaultFileCollectionFactory.java:254)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:124)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:366)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.lambda$visitContents$0(CompositeFileCollection.java:124)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.PropertyFileCollection.visitChildren(PropertyFileCollection.java:48)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitContents(CompositeFileCollection.java:124)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitStructure(AbstractFileCollection.java:366)
  at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileCollectionSnapshotter.java:47)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter$InputCollectingVisitor.visitInputFileProperty(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:133)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.visitRegularInputs(TaskExecution.java:322)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultInputFingerprinter.fingerprintInputProperties(DefaultInputFingerprinter.java:63)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionStateWithOutputs(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:123)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$captureExecutionState$1(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:82)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep$1.call(BuildOperationStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildOperationStep.operation(BuildOperationStep.java:34)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.captureExecutionState(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.lambda$execute$0(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:70)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:70)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:21)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:42)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:31)
  at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:64)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:146)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
  at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:325)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:318)
  at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:304)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463)
  at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
  at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:49)
  Caused by: org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.NoToolchainAvailableException: No matching toolchains found for requested specification: {languageVersion=11, vendor=any, implementation=vendor-specific}.
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.downloadToolchain(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:167)
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.query(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:143)
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.lambda$resolveToolchain$1(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:109)
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.resolveToolchain(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:107)
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.lambda$findMatchingToolchain$0(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:88)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProvider.calculateOwnValue(DefaultProvider.java:72)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.WithSideEffectProvider.calculateOwnValue(WithSideEffectProvider.java:54)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:82)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.FlatMapProvider.calculateOwnValue(FlatMapProvider.java:50)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.TransformBackedProvider.calculateOwnValue(TransformBackedProvider.java:82)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:108)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.withFinalValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:164)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:133)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProperty.finalValue(DefaultProperty.java:26)
  at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.finalizeNow(AbstractProperty.java:245)
  ... 143 more
  Caused by: org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.ToolchainDownloadFailedException: No locally installed toolchains match (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/toolchains.html#sec:auto_detection) and toolchain download repositories have not been configured (see https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/toolchains.html#sub:download_repositories).
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.install.DefaultJavaToolchainProvisioningService.tryInstall(DefaultJavaToolchainProvisioningService.java:113)
  at org.gradle.jvm.toolchain.internal.JavaToolchainQueryService.downloadToolchain(JavaToolchainQueryService.java:164)
  ... 161 more
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date

Please tell me what to do? Or how to configure it to build successfully.

My project is ready to build a windows desktop app